# Bootstrap 4.1 floating logo between

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a floating logo in Bootstrap 4 navigation, but unfortunately that breaks the "navbar-toggler button", this sould be right aligned on the right, but on small screens it comes under the logo on the right side...

Here the code that I have tried:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand abs" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-right">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">lorem<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">lorem</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ipsum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">lorem</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by floating logo?

Comment: I have a sticky nav on the top of the page and the logo in a png format should be visible between the nav and the main container of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you se `position: absolute` to an element

> The element is removed from the normal flow of the document, without creating any space for the element in the outline of the page. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if there is one; otherwise, it is located relative to  the  initial container block . His final position is determined by the values of  top, right, bottom, and  left.
>   This value creates a new  stacking context when the value of  z-index is not  auto. Absolutely positioned elements can have margin, and do not collapse with any other margin.

so when you set `.navbar-brand {position: absolute;}` it is removed the normal flow of the document and `navbar-toggler` is the 'only' child `.container` that has `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` (this is why `navbar-toggler` is on the right when you have other child inside `.container`).

to avoid the actual behavior you can do a lot of thing that depends on what are you expecting. try removing the `position: absolute` from the brand, adding more elements to the nav in order to get the toggle to the right, anyway the solution depends on what you want to achieve.

I hope I gave you an idea

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. Is there a solution or an alternative to position absolute?

Comment: @Bizboss if is absolutely necessary the `position: absolute` try adding an empty element to the `.navbar-brand` something like <i></i> and the toggle will go to the right (because the above explanation). if you want something more complex you have to give me an idea of what is the final result that you expect?